# How to exclude "/api" from "any"-route in Lumen router (per regex)?

Tags: regex, laravel, router, lumen, lumen-routing

I have a problem with the Lumen router (web.php):
My project includes vue.js with the vue router, so I want to point all routes to the router, what is indeed working fine.

```
$router->get('{path:.*}', function () {
    return view('app');
});
```

My problem is: I also have a few api routes, handled by Lumen/controllers:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function ($router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'authors'], function ($router) {
        $router->get('/', 'AuthorController@showAllAuthors');
        $router->get('/id/{id}', 'AuthorController@showAuthorById');
    });
});
```

Well, the route `localhost/api/authors` just works fine.
But `localhost/api/authors/1` returns the app..

I was thinking of putting in an exception to the vue route:

```
$router->get('{path:^(?!api).*$}'
```

..but this will lead to a **NotFoundHttpException**.
Is something wrong with the regex?
It should exclude all routes that start with `/api`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close.  Regex happens after the get/post statements in laravel's routes.  Like so:

```
$router->get('/{catch?}', function () { 
    return view('app'); 
})->where('catch', '^(?!api).*$');
```

Here's the docs for reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Edit:  Lumen specific should be solved in a group prefix.

```
$router->get('/{route:.*}/', function () { 
    return view('app'); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is; Lumen has no `where`. You are just able to put the regex in the get-parameter..

Comment: Sorry about that I was half asleep.  Updated the answer for Lumen.

Comment: No problem! :)
It's still not working, though I changed `$app` to `$router`again.
I splitted my app in two with one part for the backend and one part just vue. Now it's working, but..yeah, not the answer to my question. :/

Comment: @zero2579 I did some testing and made a change to my answer.  This worked perfectly for me.  Let me know what you get.

Comment: Seems to work if you don't use the vue router. I'm not sure what's the problem with that. But I guess for the main case, this is the right answer, thanks!